# Read and convert very old DVI files

Tags: tex-core, dvi, dvips

I have some very old DVI files from the 80s and 90s which were created using the version of TeX and/or LaTeX available at that time.  YAP barfs on these complaining of no preamble;  so does present-day dvips.  At one time, these files were readable and convertable to postscript.

Can anyone point me either to a dvips-like program that would work with these?  Or alternately, a hack to edit them to fix them?

One thing I am worried about is that possibly because they were originally written on a DEC-10 computer, the endianness might be wrong for DVI.  However, for some of them it's the same exact physical computer that Knuth was using at the time.  Others were written on some bleeding edge IBM mainframe of the late 80s whose model number I don't recall.

Thanks.

--pb

Comment: Are you able to point to one of these files?

Comment: missing fonts would be an issue but dvi hasn't changed since tex82, so it could be some file transfer endian or other encoding issue rather than a change in dvi

Comment: can `dviasm` read them?

Comment: Here is a link to one from 1988:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/10ONjnX89ilEq6NlzXNe0OE-cUGllWpAo/view?usp=share_link

Comment: Tried dviasm.  Barfs as follows:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xdb in position 16: invalid continuation byte

I ran it on the same file I uploaded above.

This dvi file was generated probably in the days of ascii only.  I don't see any documentation about what encodings are supported by divasm.

Hmm, well trying "ascii" also fails:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xdb in position 16: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: BTW, sorry about the extra unfinished comments:  can't keep in mind that this thing treats 'enter' as 'submit'.

I also see that this thing does not respect crlfs in the text.  Not sure how to get around it.

Comment: I believe the one I uploaded which I am running on was probably created on an IBM PC of the era, but may have been created on some humongous IBM mainframe also.  (I was working for IBM at the time.)

Comment: The file you [uploaded above](https://drive.google.com/file/d/10ONjnX89ilEq6NlzXNe0OE-cUGllWpAo/view?usp=share_link) is corrupted/not a DVI file. DVI files are supposed to start with the byte 247 (hex `f7`, binary `11110111`), while yours starts with byte 55 (hex `37`, binary `00110111`). So as @DavidCarlisle suggested above, it may be an issue with file transfer that has messed up the bytes of the file.

Comment: dviasm is only trying text encodings as it has decided it's not a dvi file so instead of dis-assembling a dvi it is trying to read it as text file with a previous dviasm dump output to re-assemble to dvi, but that will of course fail too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks loads, y'all, for helping.

Looking at the first few bytes plus rest of file for the offending dvi files, there is no uniform first byte, and other plain text parts of the dvi are not there, while my dvi files from ~1996 on are just fine.  So, either the files have bit rot (highly possible because they have been copied from media to media over the years), or there is some issue with endianness.  I note that the earlier machines I believe used 36 bit words, and later 32 bit.

So, thanks for helping, but I give up.  I still have the TeX files they came from, so if I discover I have way too much time on my hands, I can try to re-generate them, trying to compensate for all the changes to TeX and LaTeX that have happened in the meantime.

Comment: DEC-10 and DEC-20 were definitely 36-bit and ASCII.  Early implementations on other hardware were often reported in TUGboat under "site reports"; these are listed in https://tug.org/TUGboat/Contents/listkeyword.html#CatTAGSiteReports